# How to append 12 images in a row continuosly using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
function stripTags(s, n) {
    return s.replace(/<\/?(?!br\s*\/?)[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "").split(/\s+/).slice(0, n - 1).join(' ');
}

function rm(a, b, c) {
    var p = document.getElementById(a);
    var summ = summary;
    var summ = summary;
    imgtag = "";
    var i = 0;
    img = p.getElementsByTagName("img");
    imgsrc = img[i].src;
    var q = document.getElementById(b);
    var r = document.getElementById(c);

    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        if (img.length >=12) imgtag = '<a class="featured_gallery" href="' + imgsrc + '"><img src="' + imgsrc + '" /></a>';
        else if (img.length >=8) imgtag = '<a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[0].src + '"><img src="' + img[0].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[1].src + '"><img src="' + img[1].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[2].src + '"><img src="' + img[2].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[3].src + '"><img src="' + img[3].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[4].src + '"><img src="' + img[4].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[5].src + '"><img src="' + img[5].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[6].src + '"><img src="' + img[6].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[7].src + '"><img src="' + img[7].src + '" /></a>';
        else if (img.length >= 1) imgtag = '<a href="' + y + '"><img src="' + img[0].src + '" style="max-width:100%;" alt="' + x + '" /></a>';
        else imgtag = '<div class="no-img"/>';
    }
}
```

This is the code I have been using to fetch images from inside the post in the form of a gallery which contains at least 12 images.

But it's showing only one images in result

```
<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-J3qrDYeQH4U/U-rj0I955_I/AAAAAAAAG7E/ZLvcdGFVVRc/s1600/12.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-J3qrDYeQH4U/U-rj0I955_I/AAAAAAAAG7E/ZLvcdGFVVRc/s1600/12.jpg" height="213" width="320"></a>
```

But I want to get 12 images in a row like this and also want to simplify the "if" and "else if" part of code using "i array"

```
else if (img.length >=8) imgtag = '<a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[0].src + '"><img src="' + img[0].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[1].src + '"><img src="' + img[1].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[2].src + '"><img src="' + img[2].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[3].src + '"><img src="' + img[3].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[4].src + '"><img src="' + img[4].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[5].src + '"><img src="' + img[5].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[6].src + '"><img src="' + img[6].src + '" /></a><a class="featured_gallery" href="' + img[7].src + '"><img src="' + img[7].src + '" /></a>';
```

can anyone best in javascript can help me to solve this issue.

I want this strictly in javascript only

Comment: I don't see where `imgtag` is used, but you should use `+=` instead of `=` to keep the result of every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is some logical mistakes in your code , If you are using iterative statement please change

```
imgtag+='<a href="' + y + '"><img src="' + img[i].src + '" style="max-width:100%;" alt="' + x + '" /></a>'
```